# Default portrait mode for Ubuntu 20.04.1 lts

Tags: command-line, 20.04, display, display-rotation

I am needing to have Ubuntu default to portrait mode rather than landscape regardless of what monitor I plug into.

Everywhere I searched either suggested manually changing the screens, or using xrandr, but I have not seen anywhere where I can default the rotation to portrait.

Right now I am needing to change the orientation every time I plug into a new monitor.

This is for a project where I am creating and burning an image of my Ubuntu to usbs. I need them to default to portrait so that I do not have to modify every screen I connect them to.

This is a basic Ubuntu install, with the gnome desktop.

Thank you for any help/suggestions.

************************ Update

I did try to use the grub loader with fbcon=rotate: but even after updating the grub loader it did not rotate the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For me running a startup script did the trick.  I used  'xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left'  for some reason it was not working the first time around.